# undefined when loop objects Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to ask something which is actually I don't know what's wrong with my code. So, i've docs from database. Here is my docs :

```
{  
  "docs":[  
    {  
      "orderDate":{  
        "value":"2018-03-20",
        "type":"date"
      },
      "name":{  
        "value":"Abid Rakhmansyah",
        "type":"text"
      },
      "phone":{  
        "value":"082117414233",
        "type":"number"
      },
      "email":{  
        "value":"bidnth@gmail.com",
        "type":"email"
      },
      "paid":{  
        "value":true,
        "type":"boolean"
      }
    },
    {  
      "orderDate":{  
        "type":"date",
        "value":"2018-03-13T05:14:00.806Z"
      },
      "name":{  
        "value":"Iqbal Maulana",
        "type":"text"
      },
      "phone":{  
        "value":"082117414233",
        "type":"number"
      },
      "email":{  
        "value":"bidnth@gmail.com",
        "type":"email"
      },
      "paid":{  
        "type":"boolean",
        "value":false
      }
    },
    {  
      "orderDate":{  
        "value":"2018-03-20",
        "type":"date"
      },
      "name":{  
        "value":"Abdullah",
        "type":"text"
      },
      "phone":{  
        "value":"092034",
        "type":"number"
      },
      "email":{  
        "value":"nfdsi@gmail.com",
        "type":"email"
      },
      "paid":{  
        "value":true,
        "type":"boolean"
      }
    },
    {  
      "orderDate":{  
        "value":"2018-03-20",
        "type":"date"
      },
      "name":{  
        "value":"asd",
        "type":"text"
      },
      "phone":{  
        "value":"234234",
        "type":"number"
      },
      "email":{  
        "value":"bidnth@gmail.com",
        "type":"email"
      },
      "paid":{  
        "value":true,
        "type":"boolean"
      }
    },
    {  
      "orderDate":{  
        "type":"date",
        "value":"2018-03-20T06:01:54.821Z"
      },
      "name":{  
        "value":"as",
        "type":"text"
      },
      "phone":{  
        "value":"082117414233",
        "type":"number"
      },
      "email":{  
        "value":"bidnth@gmail.com",
        "type":"email"
      },
      "paid":{  
        "type":"boolean",
        "value":false
      }
    }
  ],
  "total":5,
  "limit":8,
  "page":1,
  "pages":1
}
```

I want to get only `value` property in the objects. So, i try to code like this.

```
orders.docs.forEach( function (arrayItem)
  {
    Object.keys(arrayItem.toJSON()).forEach(function(key) {
        console.log(key, JSON.stringify(arrayItem[key].value));
    });
  });
```

I think that it will be work. But, I don't know why... The result of my code doesn't show like what I expected. Here is the result of my code :

> [0] orderDate "2018-03-20"
>   [0] (node:20944) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'value'
>   of undefined

For the first loop it work fine, but when it going to 2nd loop. The `value` is undefined. What's is wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't `toJSON` turn the *object* to *JSON*. As in, a string. In that case, what are you forEach-ing on? And why would the "JSON keys" (as that's what you are forEaching, whatever that is) work on the base item?

Comment: @vlaz because when i don't use to JSON. It would return $__ undefined                                                                                                           isNew undefined

Comment: OK, but you are still getting the keys from "JSON" and using them on the base item. Unless I'm missing something JSON is a string. Doing `Object.keys` on it won't actually give you the keys from the object.

Comment: Do you have the query that gives the above results? You could perform an aggregate query that uses `$objectToArray` operator to get the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you're not just overthinking it?

Here's a <kbd>[Demo](https://codepen.io/xhynk/pen/jzKJYN?editors=0011)</kbd>

I'm sure it could be cleaned up further, but without modifying your code too much this can find the key and value pairs just fine:

```
orders = JSON.parse( orders );

orders.docs.forEach( function( arrayItem ){
    Object.keys(arrayItem).forEach( function(key) {
        console.log( key +': '+ arrayItem[key].value );
    });
});
```

Comment: I am tired :( Thank you!